# DialogFragment - show() method

Tags: java, android

I would like to see DialogFragment after pressing the button, I have two code snippets:

First:

```
        if (view.equals(b1)) {

            Fragment2 fr2 = new Fragment2();
            fr2.show(manager, "addCity"); 

        }
```

I don't understand why this tag is in the show () method, since it has no effect on program change.

Second:

```
Fragment fr = manager.findFragmentByTag("addCity"); 

        if (view.equals(b1)) { 

            if (fr != null) { 

                manager.beginTransaction().remove(fr).commit();
            }

            Fragment2 fr2 = new Fragment2(); 
            fr2.show(manager, "addCity"); 

        }
```

In the second example, I don't understand what this line of code is for:

```
Fragment fr = manager.findFragmentByTag("addCity");
```

Since the reference variable fr will always be null because there is currently no fragment under the name of such a tag.

In addition, why does this condition appear, since just the previous change fr will always be null, so this if will never come true.

```
if (fr != null) { 

                manager.beginTransaction().remove(fr).commit();
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

When you use `show(manager, "addCity")`, then second parameter is the tag for the Fragment. By using `findFragmentByTag()` with the same tag, you're looking to see if the `DialogFragment` already exists and, if it does (`fr != null`), then remove it.

This is very defensive code, probably made in an attempt to avoid users very, very quickly double tapping the button. However, because it doesn't use `showNow()` (instead of `show()`), it actually doesn't do a good job at this because `show()` is asynchronous.

In general, you don't need this code at all - just call `show()` without any of the ceremony, using whatever tag you want (the tag only matters if you're later trying to use `findFragmentByTag()` to retrieve your `DialogFragment` after the fact).

But if you *do* want to be defensive and avoid even the extremely rare chance that the user opens up two dialogs, then you need to

1) Use `showNow()` instead of `show()` so that the FragmentManager is immediately updated, ensuring that `findFragmentByTag()` actually does return the Fragment in that case
2) Instead of removing and then calling `show()` again, just don't call `show()` if it already being shown - you're just doing extra work.

This would mean your code would look like

```
if (view.equals(b1)) {
    Fragment existingDialog = manager.findFragmentByTag("addCity");
    // Only add a new dialog if it isn't already present.
    if (existingDialog == null) {
        Fragment2 fr2 = new Fragment2(); 
        fr2.showAll(manager, "addCity"); 
    }
}
```